# Passing DateTime SelectParameter to SqlDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net, sqldatasource

I have a `GridView` and `SqlDataSource` for it. `SelectCommand` is something like

```
SELECT * FROM Transfers WHERE Timestamp >= '{0}' AND Timestamp <= '{1}'
```

Parameters of `SqlDataSource`:

```
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:Parameter Name="StartDate" Type="DateTime" />
    <asp:Parameter Name="EndDate" Type="DateTime" />
</SelectParameters>
```

Then in code behind I set this parameters:

```
protected void gvTransfers_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Command.Parameters["@StartDate"].Value = DateTime.Parse(txtStartDate.Text);
    e.Command.Parameters["@EndDate"].Value = DateTime.Parse(txtEndDate.Text);
}
```

I debugged the code above and it runs and sets good `DateTime` values. But when `GridView` is being databound it throws exception

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

I spent hours on looking how to pass `DateTime` in a proper way. What am I doing wrong? Should I change SQL, markup or code behind?

I also tried `FilterParameters` and getting dates from textboxes in various formats but without success.

Comment: which sql server version are you using

Comment: Did you try using DateTime.Parse(txtStartDate.Text).ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change

```
SELECT * FROM Transfers WHERE Timestamp >= '{0}' AND Timestamp <= '{1}'
```

for

```
SELECT * FROM Transfers WHERE Timestamp >= @StartDate AND Timestamp <= @EndDate
```

For more info you can check this MSDN post: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z72eefad.aspx ;-)

Comment: Thanks! There's no exception now :). But it seems that results are not filtered properly, I'll investigate it now. I used `'{0}'` format because `FilterParameters` use it and I didn't noticed that it is different for `SelectParameters`. Confusing...

Comment: Ok, my mistake, now it's perfect.

Answer (score 4):

First, there are two things you should do:

1. Use [`DateTime.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse.aspx) (or [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx)). This will allow you to parse the string into a date, as well as getting a signal on whether the string was successfully parsed or not
2. Supply some sort of format for the parsing to use. Either a hard-coded one (if you require the user to enter the date in a specific format) or by passing a [`CultureInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx) that can be used to determine the expected date format.

Secondly, you should change the SQL query to use parameters instead, as suggested by @H27Studio.

Comment: Conversion in code behind goes well, I checked it. I also checked values of `e.Command.Parameters["@StartDate"]` (and EndDate) and they were set ok. Error is coming from SQL Server.

Comment: Thats because SQL Server is getting "{0}" and "{1}" as DateTimes instead of a real Date.

Comment: @Episodex: exactly, that's the parameter problem. Still, your parsing code is very fragile: what happens if I type "not a date" into one of the text boxes, for instance?

Comment: You're right, and I gave you +1 too (while accepting other answer) for these suggestions which I appreciate :). In my particular application I'll be using jQuery calendar control with fixed format so I'm not sure if such testing is necessary here though.